# Active directory sites and services

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, domain, active-directory, subnet

I have 192.168.1.0/23 subnet for wired connection and 192.168.2.0/24 for wireless connection. Do I need to add 192.168.2.0 in AD Sites & services. Right now I have 192.168.1.0/24 added in the subnet but not 192.168.2.0/24. So for correct user authentication to their respective DC do I need to add the 192.168.2.0/24 in the subnet?

Comment: Are these subnets connected by high speed (e.g. LAN speed) links or slower WAN links?

Answer (score 1):

Sites and Services pertains mostly to replication and different *physical* sites:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731907.aspx

> In your physical network, a site represents a set of computers that
> are connected by a high-speed network, such as a local area network
> (LAN). Typically, all computers in the same physical site reside in
> the same building or perhaps the same campus network.
>
> In AD DS, a site
> object represents the aspects of the physical site that you can
> manage, specifically, replication of directory data between domain
> controllers. You can use Active Directory Sites and Services to manage
> the objects that represent the sites and the servers that reside in
> those sites.

So no, you would not need to add another subnet for your wireless connection.